# How can I programmatically determine which tab button has been pressed in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have a tabbar with 4 buttons on it. When the user presses the A button I want to call functionA. When the user presses the B button I want to call functionB and so on.

I have implemented the UITabBarDelegate.

I have this code and it fires as expected when any button on the tabbar is pressed.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

**What I am looking for is a code snippet that illustrates how to detect which button was pressed inside the delegate presumably using item**.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to iwat's comment below I edited this to be simpler.

The following is a delegate call for the UITabBarController, rather than the UITabBar itself.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {  
    tabBarController.selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Why make it hard? You can use tabBarController.selectedIndex instead.